# components are not draggable using react beautiful dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

I've been trying to implement this watching a tutorial but this is not working. I have installed react beautiful dnd and related packages. i had to remove unrelated code to this question nor it's not allowing me to post(please ask me if needed)
.
App.tsx
.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  //states and extra code

  const onDragEnd = (result: DropResult) => {
    const { destination, source } = result;
    console.log(result);
    if (!destination) {
      return;
    }
    if (
      destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
      destination.index === source.index
    ) {
      return;
    }
    let add;
    const active = todos;
    const complete = completedTodos;
    if (source.droppableId === "TodosList") {
      add = active[source.index];
      active.splice(source.index, 1);
    } else {
      add = complete[source.index];
      complete.splice(source.index, 1);
    }
    if (destination.droppableId === "TodosList") {
      active.splice(destination.index, 0, add);
    } else {
      complete.splice(destination.index, 0, add);
    }
    setCompletedTodos(complete);
    setTodos(active);
  };
  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <div className="App">
       //code
      </div>
    </DragDropContext>
  )
}
```

here is
.
TodoList.tsx
.

```
 <Droppable droppableId='TodosList'>
                {
                    (provided) =>
                        <div className="todos" ref={provided.innerRef}{...provided.droppableProps}>
                            //code
                            {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>}</Droppable>
            <Droppable droppableId='RemoveList'>
                {(provided) =>
                        <div className="todos remove" ref={provided.innerRef}{...provided.droppableProps}>//code
                            {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                }
            </Droppable>
```

here is

.
SingleTodo.tsx
.

```
        <Draggable draggableId={todo.id.toString()} index={index}>
            {
                (provided) =>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => handleEdit(e, todo.id)} className="todos__single" {...provided.dragHandleProps}{...provided.draggableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                        //code
                    </form >
            }
        </Draggable>
```

Comment: I have hosted the site on netlify.com and now the code works but it didn't on local host. here's the repo https://github.com/Abu-0-RayhaN/TypesScript-Todo-Application